# How much space should i allocate with malloc?

Tags: string, malloc

I am writing a program that reads in strings with no more than 20 characters but i have to use malloc for dynamic memory allocation. The problem is i do not know how much space I have to free up for 20 character strings. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 21)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If I answered your question, please mark as resolved for other developers on the forums.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition. And if the length of the string can be up to 20, you need to allocate an additional byte for the `'\0'` terminator.

Answer (score 1):

For a string whose length is (up to) 20 characters, you need to allocate 21 bytes (the 1 is for the `'\0'` null character that marks the end of the string). For example:

```
char *s = malloc(21);
```

You should really define a named constant for the maximum length:

```
#define MAX_LEN 20
char *s = malloc(MAX_LEN + 1);
if (s == NULL) {
    /* malloc failed, take some corrective action or just terminate */
}
```